# Infinite queue for build while TFS Preview publishing on Azure Cloud Service

Tags: azure, build, tfs, azure-web-roles

I've created Cloud Service and linked TFS Preview Project for CI deployments. I've chosen Manual mode for triggering the builds. The previously queued builds were successfully completed and deployed. And the website based on this Cloud Service was running fine. Waiting in the queue was no more than 3-5 seconds.

Now when I click - "Queue New Build" - the new build item is created in the queue but it never runs.

I can successfully Publish project onto Azure Cloud service from VS2012 though.

What could be the most common reasons for this?

Comment: Have the previously queued builds successfully completed & deployed? Is this the only one that's sitting in the pipeline?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. The previously queued builds were successfully completed and deployed. And the website based on this Cloud Service was running fine. Waiting in the queue was no more than 3-5 seconds.

Comment: As part of process of elimination, let's see if the issue is not with the manual queuing process. What if you temporarily try to do Continuous Integration build instead? And just check-in your code to trigger a build? If that kicks off the build, then you know that the build server is doing its job.

Comment: Changed the trigger to rebuild on any check in. Checked in the code - new build item appeared in the queue and it's still there. So the problem is not with the manual triggering. Somehow server is ignoring my build requests...

Comment: http://screencast.com/t/gcbXSkDEj

Comment: It finally has been built. After 15 minutes of waiting... Doesn't seem like a good way to update testing environment. 15 minutes of waiting in queue and 15 minutes of actual deployment...

Comment: So maybe the build server was just taking a little longer than usual to kick off the build after it was queued. It'd be better if there was better feedback on the build page to let the user know what the status is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://tfs.visualstudio.com/en-us/support/current-service-status/

The hosted build has currently some issues

Comment: Now it's this url - http://tfs.visualstudio.com/en-us/support/current-service-status/